How to get a line of text in a ifstream file with another line of text?
I have a txt file that has page number data for 3 books. I am making a program to quickly change that data for a website. Here is my txt file:
0 3
1 57
2 173

The 0,1,2 is the book index's I would like to attach to the page number data. I want to take user input asking which book index I would like to get the page number data from.
Here is my code right now:
std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Robed\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Judah.site\\book_keep.txt");

if (!file.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "File could not be opened, make sure path is right!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

std::string line;


while (getline(file, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

int inputBookIndex;
std::cout << "Input book index to change page number of: ";
std::cin >> inputBookIndex;

if (inputBookIndex < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Invalid Book Index!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

file.close();

return true;

What I can't seem to figure out, though, is how do I assign the index to the page number to be able to do something like this:
Enter Book Index: 0
Page Number: 3

I tried reading other discussions online, but none of them explained what I wanted, or went nowhere.

If that is all the file contains, just use file >> int; to read one integer at a time, just like you would from std::cin.  They are the same.

Well, you have two choices - 1) read the file 1 time, parsing out the values and storing them into an array/vector that you can then index into, or 2) ask for an index and then read the file parsing the values until you find a matching index. Have you attempted either of those yet?

Your while loop keeps overwriting the line variable.  Perhaps you want a container line std::vector or if there are only 3 lines, use 3 different variables and don't bother with the loop.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/1766544
